# How do I check if a specific key is undefined if the object is undefined?

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

**What am I trying to do?**

I want to check if a specific key is `undefined`, but not able to because the higher level of the object is `undefined`.

**What is the code that currently tries to do that?**

The structure of the `character` object is (that's inside another object that exists):

```json
{
  ...
  character: { 
    ...,
    archer: { 
      ...,
      description: "shoots things" 
    }
  }
}
```

What I'd like to simply do is this, but results in an error.

```js
if (character.archer.description !== undefined) { ... }
```

A fix I have implemented, but hoping to optimize is this:

```js
...
  if (character !== undefined) {
    if (character.archer !== undefined) {
      if (character.archer.description !== undefined) {
        setDescription(character.archer.description);
      }
    }
  }
...
```

**What do I expect the result to be?**

I expect the code to realize that the if statement should run, even if `undefined` of `undefined`, that should mean `undefined` in general.

**What is the actual result?**

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined.`

**What I think the problem could be?**

Since `character.archer` is `undefined` (for now), I can not proceed to check `character.archer.description`.

Comment: The first and last lines of your proposed "workaround" go beyond the scope of the rest, FYI.

Comment: have you considered the optional chaining operator? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: You don't need a new if for each one `if (character !== undefined && character.archer !== undefined)` as the if flows from left to right this won't cause a problem. There are also some better syntaxes, such as the one mentioned by @DanielA.White you could use `character?.archer?.description !== undefined` but this is not supported by every browser and might need to be transpiled for your target.

Comment: @WBT I went ahead and edited it to remove that piece, thank you for the suggestion, it does make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) that [all evergreen browsers today support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining). You simply prepend `?` before the `.` for every level that could potentially returned `undefined` (or `null`, actually, that also works).

Example with your code:

```
if (character?.archer?.description !== undefined) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the optional chaining operator is for! It looks like this `?.` and it will return the righthand argument if the lefthand is defined, else it will return `undefined`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const description = character?.archer?.description;
  if (description !== undefined) {
    setDescription(description);
  }
}, []);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining